# I'm having an issue with my straight method in java for a card game

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

I have a project for my computer science class that involves making a card game. Here's a basic look at the Card.

```
public Card(int value, int suit) {
if (value < 1 || value > 9) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Illegal card value attempted.  The " +
            "acceptible range is 1 to 9.  You tried " + value);
}
if (suit < 0 || suit > 4) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Illegal suit attempted.  The  " + 
            "acceptible range is 0 to 4.  You tried " + suit);
}
this.suit = suit;
this.value = value;
}
public int getValue() {
return value;
}
```

My issue is that my straight method doesn't seem to be working.  What I tried to do was organize the cards in my hand from least to greatest and then do some if statements.

```
public static boolean hasStraight(Card [] cards) {
    boolean exist = false;
    Card[] other = new Card[cards.length];
    for (int i = 0; i<cards.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<cards.length; j++){
            if (cards[i].getValue()>cards[j].getValue()){
                other[i]=cards[j];
                other[j]=cards[i];
            }
        }
    }
    if (other[0].getValue()==1 && other[1].getValue()==2 && other[2].getValue()==3 && other[3].getValue()==4 && other[4].getValue()==5){
        exist = true;
    }
    else if (other[0].getValue()==2 && other[1].getValue()==3 && other[2].getValue()==4 && other[3].getValue()==5 && other[4].getValue()==6){
        exist = true;
    }
    else if (other[0].getValue()==3 && other[1].getValue()==4 && other[2].getValue()==5 && other[3].getValue()==6 && other[4].getValue()==7){
        exist = true;
    }
    else if (other[0].getValue()==4 && other[1].getValue()==5 && other[2].getValue()==6 && other[3].getValue()==7 && other[4].getValue()==8){
        exist = true;
    }
    else if (other[0].getValue()==5 && other[1].getValue()==6 && other[2].getValue()==7 && other[3].getValue()==8 && other[4].getValue()==9){
        exist = true;
    }
    else if (other[0].getValue()==6 && other[1].getValue()==7 && other[2].getValue()==8 && other[3].getValue()==9 && other[4].getValue()==1){
        exist = true;
    }
    return exist;
}
```

The length of Card[] is always 5.  Every time I call the method, it returns true even if there isn't a straight.  A straight is a condition where the values of the cards are consecutive without looping.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do in - `other[i]=cards[j] other[j]=cards[i];`, but that's not swapping. You need a temp variable for swapping. Perhaps you should be using `Arrays.sort`.

Comment: Nine card values and five suits?  That's a weird deck.  More importantly, have you stepped through the code in your debugger? That would allow you to find the error in your logic much faster and more easily than posting here.

Comment: why don't you sort your `cards`-deck? What is the intention of the "other" array? Aren't you allowed to reorder the initial deck (because you have to keep the order for a posible other method)? If so: copy the cards-deck to the other-deck and sort it. If not: just sort the cards-deck and remove the `other`-array

Comment: He has to sort based on value and not suit, but that just requires a custom comparator implementation.

Comment: Instead of writing and debugging your own sort routine, take a look at [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-). Also, as others have noted, you have a 45-card deck with 5 suits. I assume that's intentional.

Answer (score 0):

I seems to me that the sorting in the loops does not work. You can use `Arrays.sort` instead, but you have to write a `Comparator` for it or make `Card` implement `Comparable`. The code after the loops can be simplified to check if the difference of the last and first card is 4.

Comment: Can't use `Collections.sort` unless the items are in a collection; they're currently in a plain array, but [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) will work.